# Angular swiper dynamic slides not working when removing backing item

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I'm trying to use swiper as a kind of pagination, dynamically adding a slide to the end if I open something up and when swiping back I want to remove it. I have a backing array which represent the slides, having ngfor for the "ng-template swiperslide" and for a click I push an element to that array, for swiper, I react on "slidesLengthChange" and swipe to last, and on "slidePrevTransitionEnd", I pop the last element of this array. But it doesn't remove it. Tried to force updates several ways (eg. in ngAfterContentChecked: this.swiper.updateSwiper({}), manually removing the last slide, virtual slides), nothing seems to work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-angular-example-forked-sp1kq

(check the "console" tab, select "filter" to be "info")

**Additional info**

it works if other components fire this "pop()", but on the swiper events, it doesn't rerender on the "pop" (or "push")

Answer (score 0):

injecting ChangeDetectorRef and using "changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()" after the "pop" updates the view as expected